how to point an hyperlink from a citation in an external document to the bibliography in the main document?
I am using the xr-hyper package with the usual \externaldocument command (with argument "external document") in the preamble of a main document to refer to sections, equations, etc. appearing in an external document. That works fine. Then, I also have references to sections, equations, etc. appearing in the main document as well as extra citations some in common with the main document some specific to the external document, all appearing in the external document. So, I load the xr-hyper package and use the same \externaldocument command (now with argument "main document") in the external document preamble. This also works fine for sections, equations, etc., i.e., the hyperlink in the external document points to the correct location in the main document. However, the hyperlinks from the citations that are printed in the external document (which are only those common to the main document, see below) do not point to the bibliography list printed at the end of the main document at all (nor to the correct location within that list), but to the top of the external document pdf. In addition, the citations that are specific to the external document are not printed in the .pdf, which means they also do not appear in the bibliography at the end of the main document. Obviously, I use the hyperref package in both main and external documents. Is there a solution for this problem with the external document citations?
Next, the MWE.
First, the main document .tex file:
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument{./external}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false,linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Main document\label{sec:1}}

\subsection{Main document details\label{sec:1.1}}

Main document contains a reference to section \ref{sec:E.1} in the external document, as well as a citation 1 \cite{W00}, a citation 2 \cite{L00}, and a citation 3 \cite{D21}.

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document} 

Second, the external document .tex file:
% external.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument{./main}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false,linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{External document\label{sec:E}}

\subsection{External document details\label{sec:E.1}}

External document contains a reference to Section \ref{sec:1.1} in the main document, as well as a citation 3 \cite{D21} appearing also in the main document and a citation 4 \cite{J92} appearing only in the external document.

\end{document}

and  finally the bibliography .bib file:
@article{W00,
  author = "Wayne, J.",
  title = "Article with volume number and doi",
  journal = "Journal A",
  volume = "X",
  number = "Y",
  pages = "1-2",
  year = "2000",
  doi  = "10.1007/...",
  url  = ""
}

@article{L00,
  author = "Lee, B. and Lee, A.",
  title = "Article without volume number, but with url",
  journal = "Journal B",
  volume = "",
  number = "Y",
  pages = "3-4",
  year = "2000",
  doi  = "",
  url  = "https://..."
}
enter code here

@book{J92,
  author = "Jordan, M. and Johnson, M. and Pippen, S.",
  title = "{Fundamentals of Basketball}",
  edition = "1",
  publisher = "Chicago University Press",
  location  = "Chicago",
  isbn = "87654321",
  doi = "",
  url = "",
  year = "1992"
}

@inproceedings{D21,
  author = "Delon, A.",
  title = "{Article title}",
  editor = "Edith, I.",
  booktitle = "{Proceedings of Symposium A}",
  series = "Series of Symposia Proceedings",
  volume = "1",
  edition = "2",
  pages = "5-6",
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
  location = "London",
  isbn = "12345678",
  doi = "",
  url = "",
  year = "2021",
  eventtitle = "Symposium A",
  venue = "Oxford",
  eventdate = "2020-09-01/2020-09-05"
}


is your bib really a .tex file or is that a typo?

@cfr: typo. sorry about that!
